# Issue with the request using JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying out using JSON for the first time. I wanted to test out printing a simple "Hello" to see if I was getting any print statement however everytime I click on the button it says "There was a problem with the request":
[image]
[image]

I tried following my schools instructions on how to do it, and it seems there should be no issue, but here I am asking a question about this. Can anybody explain to me why I am getting this error?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Lab06 - INT222_162   </title>
    <script src="lab06.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <style>   
      .lab06 {width:100%; margin:auto;text-align:center;}
      .table-1 {width:900px; margin:auto; border:2px solid;}
      .table-1 td {border:1px solid; text-align:center;}
      .table-1 tr:nth-child(odd)  {background: #cccccc; color:#000000;}
      .table-1 tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ffffff; color:#000000;}
      .table-1 th {background: #00ff00;border:1px solid;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="lab06">
      <h3><mark>JSON TEST</mark></h3>
      <div id="data">
        <p><button title="ajaxButton" onclick="makeRequest();">list of Canadian Provinces &amp; Territories</button></p>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var dt=new Date(document.lastModified);   // Get document last modified date
          document.write('This page was last updated on '+dt.toLocaleString()) 
        </script>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
  var httpRequest;

  function makeRequest() {
    var url = 'https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~emile.ohan/int222/labs/lab06/provTerr.json'; 
    // make an HTTP request object

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }

    // register a request listener
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = showContents;
    // make the HTTP request 
    httpRequest.open('GET', url, true);
    httpRequest.send(null);
  }

  // the function that handles the server response

  function showContents() {

   //  check for response state
   //  0      The request is not initialized
   //  1      The request has been set up
   //  2      The request has been sent
   //  3      The request is in process
   //  4      The request is complete

    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      // check the respone code
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // The request has succeeded
        // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data

        var jsArray = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);




        document.write("Helloooo");





      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = str;
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't use AJAX in a `file:///` URL. Upload it to a server.

Comment: Furthermore you can't use AJAX to call things on another server.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. All you've established is that the `status` is not `200`. Look and see what status it is. Use the developer tools in your browser. Check the Console for error messages. Check the Network tab to see if the request you are sending and the response you are getting back are what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your browser URL should start with `http://` or `https://` instead of `file://`, they're different protocols.

### Full explanation

You're trying to access a page using `https://` but you opened the file directly through a browser which means you're on `file://`, this is a security measure to prevent scripts from accessing your hard drive and sending it out over the internet.

Try installing a local web server like WAMP or the NodeJS http-sever module and run the script through that, once you're sure you're on HTTP(S) your script should work.

Side note: Try using the Chrome debugger tools (F12 on Windows and Command + Alt + I on OS X) and check the console for errors, it will save you lots of time